# Coda Slider 2.0 plugin not working on Wordpress install

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slider, coda

I'm trying to use Coda Slider 2.0 on the home page of a Wordpress theme, and it is stuck on the preloader. In Firefox and Safari I can see the animated looping progess bar, background style and "Loading...". In Chrome I see the same, but the image link to the progress bar is broken.

Here's the section of code I'm using on the header.php file of my page for this purpose (jQuery is loaded earlier in the header):

```
<?php if (is_home()) {?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/coda-slider-2.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
        });
     </script>
<?php } ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> class="coda-slider-no-js">

<div id="wrapper">

    <?php include("contactPanel.php"); ?>

    <img id="agent" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/agent.png"></img>
    <h1><a href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>">Site Title</a></h1>

    <div id="contentWrap" class="clearfix">

        <ul id="navigation">
            <a class="current" href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>"><li>Services</li></a> |
            <a href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>/clients"><li>Clients</li></a> |
            <a href="<?php blogInfo('url'); ?>/news"><li>News</li></a>
        </ul>

        <div id="content" class="clearfix">

            <?php if (is_home()) {?>
                <div id="LMOD" class="clearfix">

                    <div class="coda-slider-wrapper">
                        <div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="panel-wrapper">
                                    <h2 class="title">Panel 1</h2>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas metus nulla, commodo a sodales sed, dignissim pretium nunc. Nam et lacus neque. Sed volutpat ante id mauris laoreet vestibulum. Nam blandit felis non neque cursus aliquet. Morbi vel enim dignissim massa dignissim commodo vitae quis tellus. Nunc non mollis nulla. Sed consectetur elit id mi consectetur bibendum. Ut enim massa, sodales tempor convallis et, iaculis ac massa. Etiam suscipit nisl eget lorem pellentesque quis iaculis mi mattis. Aliquam sit amet purus lectus. Maecenas tempor ornare sollicitudin.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="panel-wrapper">
                                    <h2 class="title">Panel 2</h2>
                                    <p>Proin nec turpis eget dolor dictum lacinia. Nullam nunc magna, tincidunt eu porta in, faucibus sed magna. Suspendisse laoreet ornare ullamcorper. Nulla in tortor nibh. Pellentesque sed est vitae odio vestibulum aliquet in nec leo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="panel-wrapper">
                                    <h2 class="title">Panel 3</h2>
                                    <p>Cras luctus fringilla odio vel hendrerit. Cras pulvinar auctor sollicitudin. Sed lacus quam, sodales sit amet feugiat sit amet, viverra nec augue. Sed enim ipsum, malesuada quis blandit vel, posuere eget erat. Sed a arcu justo. Integer ultricies, nunc at lobortis facilisis, ligula lacus vestibulum quam, id tincidunt sapien arcu in velit. Vestibulum consequat augue et turpis condimentum mollis sed vitae metus. Morbi leo libero, tincidunt lobortis fermentum eget, rhoncus vel sem. Morbi varius viverra velit vel tempus. Morbi enim turpis, facilisis vel volutpat at, condimentum quis erat. Morbi auctor rutrum libero sed placerat. Etiam ipsum velit, eleifend in vehicula eu, tristique a ipsum. Donec vitae quam vel diam iaculis bibendum eget ut diam. Fusce quis interdum diam. Ut urna justo, dapibus a tempus sit amet, bibendum at lectus. Sed venenatis molestie commodo.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="panel-wrapper">
                                    <h2 class="title">Panel 4</h2>
                                    <p>Nulla ultricies ornare erat, a rutrum lacus varius nec. Pellentesque vehicula lobortis dignissim. Ut scelerisque auctor eros sed porttitor. Nullam pulvinar ultrices malesuada. Quisque lobortis bibendum nisi et condimentum. Mauris quis erat vel dui lobortis dignissim.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .coda-slider -->
                    </div><!-- .coda-slider-wrapper -->

                </div><!--LMOD-->
            <?php } ?>
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do it use the Developer menu in Safari (Preferences>>Advanced) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox to see what JS is loading and if there are JS errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error I'm getting with Firebug says "$("#coda-slider-1").codaSlider is not a function". I'm pretty new, could you point me in the right direction on what to do?

Comment: UPDATE: Okay, it looks like my javascript files for the coda slider plugin aren't loading. When I copy the code directly into the main javascript file I'm using for all my other functions, it works. However, I can't seem to find a problem in my links to these files in my header. Any ideas?